# Proving $\mu\ast K_n\to\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution, harmonic-analysis

> Let $\{K_n\}$ be approximating unit and $\mu\in M(\mathbb{T})$. Show that $\mu\ast K_n\to \mu$ weakly means $$\int f(t)d(\mu\ast K_n)(t)\to\int f(t)d\mu(t)$$

Suppose $\mu\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$, I know that $\mu\ast K_n\to\mu$ and we are done. but what happens when $\mu\not\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$? How can I prove that?

**EDIT:** I know that $K_n\in L^1$ and that $\int_\mathbb{T}K_n(s)\frac{dt}{2\pi}=1$ but I can't procceed from here.

**EDIT2:** Maybe to use $f\ast K_n\to f$ if $f\in L^1$?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How is the measure $K*μ$ defined? What is the (minimal) space of functions $f$ involved in the definition of weak convergence?

Comment: $f\in C^1(\mathbb{T})$ and the convolution is defined by the formula $\int_\mathbb{T}f(t)d(\mu\ast K_n)=\int_{\mathbb{T}}\int_{\mathbb{T}}f(s+t)d\mu(t)dK_n(s)$

Comment: This seems unlikely since $K_n\to\delta_0$ as distributions, so $dK_n(s)=K_n'(s)ds$ would converge to the derivative $\delta_0'$. It would be more reasonable if it were $K_n(s)ds$ instead.

Comment: @DanisFischer : Did you ever figure this out? I have the same question.