# Prove $\hat{f}(\omega)\neq 0$ if $\{f(x-t)\}_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

> Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. s.t $\{f(x-t)\}_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ is complete. Prove that $\hat{f}(\omega)\neq 0$ for all $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$

Suppose the system is complete for any $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, $$\Vert g-\sum_{t}f(x-t)\Vert\le \epsilon$$ which means $$\int |g-\sum_tf(x-t)|\to 0$$ and now I thought applying the trasnform and getting contradiction. But where is the contradiction?

Comment: How do the Fourier transforms of different translates of $f$ compare?

Comment: it creates trigonometric polynom which by weirestrass is supposed to be unique and with coefficients which are not zero? Isn't that correct only on $\mathbb{T}$?

Comment: Right, so that trig polynomial $\times$ the Fourier of $f$ approximates the Fourier of $g$. Therefore, if the Fourier of $f$ had a zero at $\omega$ then so would the Fourier of $g$. So you could not approximate $g$ whose Fourier is not zero at $\omega$.

Comment: thanks. can you also have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145259/proving-mu-ast-k-n-to-mu please?

Comment: You surely mean $$\left\|g(x)-\sum_{k=1}^n c_k\,f(x-t_k)\right\|<ϵ$$ for some collection $t_1<t_2<...<t_n$ and some coefficients $c_1,...,c_n$. The linear hull is made up of finite linear combinations with arbitrary coefficients and completeness refers to the closure of it.